# How to to clear the tiki-system cache?

Tags: tiki-wiki

I am using [Tiki Wiki](https://tiki.org), and I change to login with an LDAP server, I already made all the configurations but when I try to login with a user from my LDAP server give me a blank page. I saw a solution on TIKIWIKI doc's, they say to clear the cache but I dont know how to clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the Tiki caches by going to tiki-admin_system.php when logged in as an admin, there is a link on the Settings part of the main Tiki menu, and one on the Quick Admin module (if enabled).

You can also clear the cache from the command line by doing

```
php console.php cache:clear
```

More info [here](https://doc.tiki.org/clearing+cache)

(however, if you are running Tiki 16.2 there is a bug in LDAP which also produces this sort of blank page error. This will be fixed in 16.3 which will be released soon, in the mean time you can download a nightly build from [here](https://dev.tiki.org/Daily+Build))

Comment: Thank you I already clear the cache but still give me a blank page. I'm using Tike Version 16.2.. I'm going to change to LTS (long term support)